# Parsing complicated query parameters

Tags: python, database, parsing

My Python server receives jobs that contain a list of the items to act against, rather like a search query term; an example input:

```
(Customer:24 OR Customer:25 OR (Group:NW NOT Customer:26))
```

So when a job is submitted, I have to parse this recipient pattern and resolve all those customers that match, and create the job with that input.

To complicate matters, customers can join and leave groups at any time, and the job should be updated live when this happens.

So as groups change membership, I have to notify all currently-running jobs about it (and they do their thing).

How is best to parse, apply and store (in my RDBMS) this kind of list of constraints?

- Parsing: `eval()`, hand-written FSM eating characters, yacc/bison/?, or?
- applying: how would you store these constraints, and evaluate them?
- storing: in a database, a row per term with a evaluation-order and a NOT/AND/OR op field; or as a blob?

Comment: customer 24 twice? what does OR mean? Who is writing this stuff, a programmer or an end-user? To get work done on 3 different customers, an end-user will write 1 and 2 and 3, a programmer will write c==1 or c==2 or c==3. What do you mean by "job should be updated live"? What does a "job" consist of? What parts of it would need to be updated?

Comment: We all guessed it was a typo. Now try to answer the questions.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel when there are already things like SQLAlchemy or django's ORM? Django is especially pretty great when it comes to parsing a request's data and creating a good SQL statement.

Comment: @mawimawi if there are tools to parse queries that arrive as strings please post them as answers, giving not just the name but also explaining *how*

Comment: @Will I have to apologize. After re-reading your question I realized that this has nothing to do with HTTP GET or POST stuff, but just a long string with parentheses that is being sent to your program. In that case neither Django's ORM nor SQLAlchemy is of much help, since your problem seems primarily to be about parsing this string and creating an SQL statement for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest pyparsing (http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which lets you describe a grammar neatly and gives you a tree filled with data. Then, hopefully, your syntax is close enough to SQL so that you can trivially form a "where" clause from the parsing results.

You may pickle and store the parsed tree, or the unparsed requests, or ready-made SQL clauses. This depends on how often will you fetch and reuse them, and whether you need to inspect the database by other means and see the queries. I see no point in storing the queries in a non-blob form unless you want to run interesting selects against them — and if you do, you probably need an XML database or something else that supports trees easily.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 0):

Consider using SQL instead of inventing yet another mini language:

```
(
cust.id = 24
or cust.id = 25
or (cust.id = cust_group.cust_id and cust_group.id = 'NW' and cust.id != 26)
) // or somthing similar
```

SQL injection worries? You'd need to parse it (not too difficult if your expressions are suitably limited) and check it for plausibility whatever language it was written in.